# Why $f$ is not supposed to be differentiable?

Tags: calculus, continuity

$ f(x)= | x^2-1|= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             x^2 -1&   if  & x \geq 1 \\
             \\ 1-x^2 &  if & -1 < x < 1 \\
             \\ x^2-1 &  if  & x \leq -1
             \end{array}
   \right. $

We know $f$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$-{-1,1}, but what about x=-1 and x=1?

$ \lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{f(h+1)-f(1)}{h}} = \lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{(h+1)^2-1}{h}} = \lim_{h\to 0}{h+2} = 2 $

Maybe it could be cause:

$ \lim_{h\to 0^+}{\frac{f(h+1)-f(1)}{h}} = \lim_{h\to 0^+}{\frac{|(h+1)^2-1|}{h}}= \lim_{h\to 0^+}{\frac{|h(h+2)|}{h}} = \lim_{h\to 0^+}{h+2} = 2 $

$ \lim_{h\to 0^-}{\frac{f(h+1)-f(1)}{h}} = \lim_{h\to 0^-}{\frac{|(h+1)^2-1|}{h}}= \lim_{h\to 0^-}{\frac{|h(h+2)|}{h}} = \lim_{h\to 0^-}{-(h+2)} = -2 $

Then the limit $\nexists$.

In this case, why I can take the second expression of the function to calculate the limit? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot simplify $\frac{f(h+1)-f(1)}{h}$ to $\frac{(h+1)^2-1}{h}$ if $h<0$. Instead you get $-\frac{(h+1)^2-1}{h}$ and that minus sign creates the nondifferentiability.

Comment: But $h$ is considered to be a distance, right? Then $h>0$.

Comment: It is usually not considered to be a distance, no. Most sources allow it to have either sign. (The choice of notation doesn't actually matter, though; if you prefer to enforce $h>0$ then the leftward slope at $1$ is $\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(1)-f(1-h)}{h}$ and the rightward slope is $\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}$ which still creates the problem.)